# I am trying to refactor This code to a functional component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to refactor this code to a functional component so I dont need to wrap this in a Product Consumer. I keep getting error unexpected token in my functional component and can't figure out why.

This is the original

```
           <ProductConsumer>
                {value => {
                  return value.clothing.map(product => {
                    return <Product key={product.id} product={product} />;
                  });
                }}
              </ProductConsumer>
```

This is the functional Component

```
                          const ProductListComponent = (props) => {
                const [loading, setloading] = useState(true)
            const productConsumer = useContext(ProductContext);

            const { cart } = productConsumer;

            useEffect(() => {


                (async () => {
                    await domLoaded;
                    setTimeout(() => {
                    console.log('DOM is loaded');
                    setLoading(false);
                    console.log(loading)
                    }, 200);
                })();


            }, [domLoaded, loading, params, props.location.pathname]);
                if (loading === false) {
                    return (
                    <React.Fragment>
                    <Slide>
                        <header className="bg py-5 mb0 container-fluid clothing ">
                        <div className="container h-100">
                            <div className="row h-100 align-items-center">
                            <div className="col-lg-12">
                                <h1 className="display-4 text-white mt-5 mb-2 text-center">
                                {props.title}
                                </h1>
                                <p
                                style={props.textStyle}
                                className="lead mb-5 text-white  text-center"
                                >
                                {props.description}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </header>

                        <div className="py-0    ">
                        <div className="container">
                            <div className="row">

                            return props.items.productConsumer.map(product => {
                return <Product key={product.id} product={product} />;
            });

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </Slide>
                    </React.Fragment>
                    )
                }else if (loading === true) {
                return <Spinner />;
                }
            }

            export default withRouter(ProductListComponent)
```

I decided to pass in the value.clothing as props so i can reuse the component

Answer (score 0):

The body of a functional component is just a Function, you don't need the wrapping curly brackets:

```
function Component(props) {
  return props.items.productConsumer.map(product => {
    return <Product key={product.id} product={product} />;
  });
}
```

Comment: Im still getting same error let me post my entirec component

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct answer.

```
  {props.items.productConsumer.map(product => {
              return <Product key={product.id} product={product} />;
            })}
```